# How do I create a snapshot of a VM in Oracle Cloud (OCI)?

Tags: snapshot, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I recently set up a Ubuntu Linux instance in Oracle Cloud. I'm used to take snapshots of VM's so I can roll back if something later goes wrong. In Digitalocean (droplet) this is as simple as pressing a button but in Oracle Cloud I can't seem to find this functionality. I've read documentation and Googled but to no avail. Also seems Oracle have several different cloud offerings with similar naming which makes it hard to find relevant information.

Comment: Hm.. this question doesn't get much traction and also got a close vote. Am I in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1):

- Select your instance
- Go to **Boot Volume** submenu (bottom left)
- Click the **Boot Volume** attached to the instance
- In **Boot Volume**, go to the **Boot Volume Backup** submenu (bottom left)
- Click **Create Boot Volume Backup**

This volume can be used to start a new instance and will help to restore your server to the last (backed up) good configuration.

Comment: Could be I'm not familiar with the terminology, but is taking a backup of the boot volume the same as taking a backup of the complete machine?

Comment: Boot volume size of an instance will be between 30G - 50G. which can be backed up before any major activity. You can configure your application related stuffs in the Block volume. So if your OS goes to panic state, you can role back your server using old Boot volume backup and your app is still safe as it is is in the Block volume. Boot volume can be initiated by going to storage >> boot volume and start backup or click on the instance, scroll down and to the left side you can see boot volume.

Answer (score 0):

OCI does not have this functionality. You can make a backup of the boot volume, but you cannot restore this backup to your instance. You can create a new boot volume out of a backup and create a new instance using it. The backup does not include memory (you have to boot again) nor any instance settings (you have to enter them again as there is no way to 100% store a server config as a template) - for example, your public IP address will be gone forever if you need to restore from backup.

It's a head scratcher.